# Running Rspec from an entirely different sinatra app?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rspec2

I'm currently trying to run a sinatra framework that downloads code from a repo, executes rspec on the code and then processes the results from RSpec. However, I'm having trouble getting rspec to run when i call it from a different application.

I keep getting the following error:

```
/Users/dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:147:in `block in replace_gem': rspec-core is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rspec:22:in `<main>'
```

After running tons of output, it basically boils down ruby not switching to the correct directory before executing bundle exec. I've tried just about anything to get it to work with no success... It seems even if I change the directory, it will continue to attempt to run RSpec on the application i'm on, rather than the one i want to do it.

```
  Dir.chdir('../target_app'){
    exe = "bundle exec rspec spec"
    `#{exe}`
  }
```

I've also tried backticks, exec and system() like this with no success.

```
`cd ../target_app && bundle exec rspec spec`
```

I have also tried things like ChildProcess with no success:

```
  p = ChildProcess.build('bundle', 'exec', 'rspec', 'spec')
  p.io.inherit!
  p.cwd = '../target_app'
  p.start
```

Any clue or help on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

I've also tried `bundle install --binstub --path vendor`

with this code:

```
  Dir.chdir('../target_app'){
    puts `pwd`.chomp
    exe = "bin/rspec spec -o ../tmp.txt"
    puts exe
    `#{exe}`
  }
```

I get this output:

```
/Users/me/dev/target_app
bin/rspec spec -o ../tmp.txt
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:223:in `block in replace_bin_path': can't find executable rspec (Gem::Exception)
    from bin/rspec:16:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2):

Generate binstubs for Bundler `bundle install --binstubs` and use the binstub instead of rspec so that the proper rspec and Gemfile is always used.

http://gembundler.com/v1.2/man/bundle-exec.1.html (more information on binstubs in that online man page)

Comment: +1. I always do this now, for every project. I also add `--path vendor`, it really helps to sandbox the whole project from anything else I'm working on. YMMV

Comment: I've just tried this, but still no success. I've followed the directions from here: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/15346721484/use-bundlers-binstubs and I still get the same error. I think i need to load the gemfile from that folder, but i'm not sure if that works or that's the right way

Comment: You want to execute `bin/rspec` relative to your initial app, not the target app. Set the path to bin/rspec before doing a `Dir.chdir` using `rspec = File.expand_path("./bin/rspec")` (if that works, getting the full path based off of `File.dirname(__FILE__)` might be more robust.